# Which design pattern used in Java's toLowerCase() method

Tags: java, design-patterns

I went for an interview and they asked me this question. Which design pattern(s) are used in `toLowerCase()` case? How would you design a `toLowerCase()` method for minimal maintenance.

Comment: Design pattern? Maybe they meant algorithm... http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/lang/String.java#String.toLowerCase%28java.util.Locale%29

Comment: I'm not sure I'd say that any design pattern at all is used there.  Maybe a Flyweight pattern?  But not everything is a pattern, maybe sometimes it's just bit manipulation.

Comment: Also "minimal maintenance" is almost impossible because of so many possible Locales

Comment: is there way to identify after looking method I can identify design pattern used in java code.

Comment: Not really. Again, not everything is a design pattern. You don't write one method with a design pattern in mind, you write a collection of use-cases. For which, `toLowerCase()` really only has one

Comment: defensive copy and immutability but is the "design pattern" term may be applied for them ?

Comment: but lets consider the jdk toLowerCase(), which design pattern used on that

Comment: Strategy? As in, the Locale you pass in (or the system default locale) is something you can select at runtime to control the behaviour of the algorithm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally toLowerCase() method we use to make all letters of string in lowercase...so may be Decorator Pattern is used.

The Decorator Pattern provides a mechanism to embellish the behaviour of an object without changing its essential interface. A decorated object should be able to be substituted wherever the original (non-decorated) object was expected. Decoration typically does not involve modifying the source code of the original object and decorators should be able to be combined in flexible ways to produce objects with several embellishments.